# Make a difference between empty value and 0

Tags: php

Its' about a form to enter results of a soccer tournament.

The form got the already inputed data from the db and writes it into the value argument of the html form. If the value in the db NULL so in the html i got

```
value=""`
```

It's important that games with no inputs doesn't make a change in the db so i filter it before i do the query. But now could it happen that a game ends 0 : 0 But the db won't safe that. How can i say the system its not empty/NULL it is 0?

```
      if(!empty($_POST[$tore_heim] OR !empty($_POST[$tore_gast]))){
         $spiele_save = "UPDATE spiele SET tore_heim = '".$_POST[$tore_heim]."', tore_gast = '".$_POST[$tore_gast]."' WHERE id_spiele = ".$spiele_id[$i]."";    
         $spiele_save = mysqli_query($con, $spiele_save);};
        };
```

Comment: `isset(...) && strlen(...) > 0`…?!

Comment: Maybe check with `===` or `!==` operator. This will help maybe

Comment: The simple answer is to look at the [manual for `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and there you will see that Zero is considered EMPTY

Comment: @RiggsFolly So how to bypass it and make `'0'` not empty?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: See @Justinas answer. That is one way

Comment: if(!empty($_POST[$tore_heim]) OR !empty($_POST[$tore_gast]) or (isset($_POST[$tore_gast]) && $_POST[$tore_gast]==0) ){

Comment: @Fabrizio Cocco I think deceze answer best isset(...) && strlen(trim(...)) > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you deceze

```
    if(isset($_POST[$tore_heim]) && strlen($_POST[$tore_heim]) > 0 
    OR
    isset($_POST[$tore_gast]) && strlen($_POST[$tore_gast]) > 0)
```

The Problem is solved!

Answer (score -1):

Check if value is `'0'`: `!empty($_POST[$tore_gast])) || $_POST[$tore_gast] === '0'`

Comment: This runs the risk of accessing an undefined index and producing a warning! It tries to access `$_POST[$tore_gast]` when it's `empty`, which could mean it either **doesn't exist** or is `0`.

Answer (score -1):

look at this example.

function isEmpty( $variable ){

```
    return ( 
     !isset($_POST[$variable]) ||
     ( empty($_POST[$variable]) && $_POST[$variable] !== "0" ) 
    );
```

}

if ( !isEmpty($tore_heim)  ){

```
    // run your code here...
```

}

Comment: Why are you testing for `empty` again when you have already established the value to be `isset`…?

Comment: because isset does not checks for space or an empty string. isset only checks if the variable is set, and then I checked if the variable does not contain any empty values. @deceze

Comment: Then just use `!$variable`, it has the same outcome and doesn't use superfluous error suppression. `empty` is `isset` + `!`, you've already done the `isset`, don't (implicitly) repeat it.